# ^[ escape in shell prompt

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-prompt

#### Problem

I am writing an [application](https://github.com/glfmn/glitter) in rust (for fun) that allows me to use DSL to pretty-print git repository stats into my bash shell prompt.

However, I am having an [issue](https://github.com/ogham/rust-ansi-term/issues/36) with the [library](https://github.com/ogham/rust-ansi-term) I use to format text in the terminal.  It uses an escape I haven't seen before, `^[`, in the output. It seems to affect the line wrapping such that the text wraps onto the same line before the end of the terminal.

You can see here a demonstration in [gnome shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxqX8.gif) and in [hyper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqXS3.gif).

#### Replication

Create a file `shell.txt` with the following contents:

```
^[[1;32m\u^[[0m^[[32m@\h^[[0m:^[[1;34m\w^[[0m
```

Set your prompt command to be the following:

```
__set_prompt() {
    PS1="$(cat shell.txt)"
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=__set_prompt
```

#### Question

What is the `^[` escape?

Is there a simple fix to get my shell to recognize the line width-properly?

```
bash --version 4.4.12(1)-release
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a representation of a literal escape character (ASCII 0x1b). A simpler way to write `shell.txt` would be

```
\e[1;32m\u\e[0m\e[32m@\h\e[0m:\e[1;34m\w\e[0m
```

To make sure the shell can accurately compute the size of your prompt, you need to wrap the non-printing characters in `\[...\]`.

```
\[\e[1;32m\]\u\[\e[0m\e[32m\]@\h\[\e[0m\]:\[\e[1;34m\]\w\[\e[0m\]
```

Comment: For an explanation of what the escapes are being used for, see [here](http://pueblo.sourceforge.net/doc/manual/ansi_color_codes.html)